# Passing parameter to stateful widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to pass a parameter uid to a stateful widget like this:

```
class BoardBody extends StatefulWidget {
  String uid;
  BoardBody({
    @required this.uid,
  });
```

When I try to access it at initstate, I got a null.  However, if I hot reload the page, the value widget.uid is printed out.  Did I do anything wrong?  I have like to have the uid available so that I can pull some data from the DB.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    print("user id");
    print(widget.uid);
    super.initState();
  }
```

I have passed the uid data to the widget like this:

```
BoardBody(uid: uid)
```

Comment: Your code looks right. Share the code where you are passing the parameter.

Comment: @YoBo, I have passed the uid into BoardBody like BoardBody(uid: uid)

Comment: try to call the `super.initState()` befor accessing `widget.uid`.

Comment: Are you sure that the uid is not null when you pass it the first time?

Comment: @YoBo, oh, it could be null, let me check again....

Comment: @Yobo, indeed, it is null, uid is generated in the same page as BoardBody, BoardBody is just a widget inside the dashboard page.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to you used routes in the main.dart.
Thus, initState() loads after it builds Scaffold.

If you try to build the screen/Widget with MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BoardBody()), you'll see the result (printed uid).

Comment: it is actually a widget in the dashboard page, the widget name is BoardBody, so it is not from some route actually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // TODO: implement initState
    print("user id");
    print(widget.uid);
  }
```

So super.initState() should be above your print. This should work.